# Installing Ubuntu on RAID 1, but not using all disks capacity? And what is HotSpare?

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, hard-drive, raid

I'm totally new to all this hard disks matter and even newer to topic with RAID.
I hope somebody can help me!

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (BioLinux) on Dell Precision T7500, with Dell PERC 6/i Adapter RAID controller, but only 1.8TB usable.

I have 8 disks, totaling up to 12TB, how do I activate and use them all?

I created new Virtual disk and followed through the short guide from the below 2 links to install my BioLinux with USB stick.

http://www.orangecomputers.com/node/?command=kb&docid=25

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llvGKVYSQ4A

After successfully booting, gparted only showing 1.8TB size available and there is only 1MB of unallocated space.

How do I activate back the other disks and get the Ubuntu (BioLinux) run on total 12TB space (or at least 6TB)? Is it possible?

Something to tweak in the Configuration Utility? Use other levels of RAID?

And what is "HotSpare"??

Greatly appreciate any help from anyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use RAID 1, the disks are all duplicates of each other.  If you have the 12 disks, the data will be duplicated 12 times up to the capacity of the smallest disk.

What you want is either RAID 0, 5, 6, or 10.

In RAID 0, all the disks are used to store data with no redundancy.  The total space would be the smallest disk size * 8.

In RAID 5, data is stored with parity bits.  This allows a single disk to fail and data still be readable.  The size of the virtual disk would be the size of the smallest disk * 7.

In RAID 6, it is basicly the same as RAID 5 except data is stored with 2 differenty parity bits.  This means that 2 disks can fail and data is still recoverable.  The size of the virtual disk would be the size of the smallest disk * 6.

In RAID 10, is groups of disks in RAID 1 combined in RAID 0.  This allows for the possibility of multiple disks to fail as long as they are not in the same RAID 1 group.  The size of your RAID 1 groups will determine the final size of the array.

Note not all RAID Controllers support RAID 5 & 10, but according to dell  your controller does support RAID (0,1,5,6,10)
(http://www.dell.com/learn/us/en/04/campaigns/dell-raid-controllers)

Hot Spares are used as spare disks in the RAID Array.  When a disk fails, (assuming it is a recoverable error) the array will recreate the data that was on the failed disk on the hot spare.

Overall I would recommend NOT using RAID 0 unless the information you are storing in VERY UNIMPORTANT.  If ANY of the 8 disks would fail, it would mean the loss of all of your data.
RAID 1 as you have found out crates many duplicates increasing read speed, but there is really no reason to put 8 disks in RAID 1.
I would recommend either doing RAID 5, 6, or 10 depending on the disk space your require and the data integrity needed.

Comment: Thank you so much Eric for the elaboration and check up on RAID compatibility!

We would like to have as much space as possible, moderated with the best data integrity we can get. 
We are dealing with Biological data thus data loss is totally unfavorable although we do backups once in a while.

To confirm, "The size of the virtual disk would be the size of the smallest disk",
do u mean if I have 1TB disk, the space i have in the end is only 1TB?

Sorry I don't understand the "* 8/7/6"

In RAID10,how many RAID1 group can be created? E.g. 4TB in 1 group, 8TB in another, array will have 4 or 8TB?

Comment: When saying the size of the disk is the size of the smallest disk, if you were to put 2 disks in raid, the larger disk is only used to the capacity of the smaller disk. Example: RAID 0 with a 1TB and a 2TB: size is 2TB as the 1TB is the smaller disk so it would cap the 2TB at its capacity.  Example: RAID 1 with a 1TB and a 2TB: total space is 1TB which is the size of the smallest disk.

Comment: With the total capacity, (assuming all disks are the same size) if you have 8 disks in raid 0, you will have all 8 disks storage for your use, but with no redundancy.  If you use raid 5, you will be using 7 disks for storage and 1 disk for parity.  This way if a single disk fails, the storage array can be rebuilt when you insert a new disk.  In raid 6, you will be using 6 disks for storage and 2 disks for parity.  This way if 2 disks fail, the array can still be rebuilt.

Comment: With raid 10, you would create raid 1 partitions.  These would then be used to create a raid 0 partition of the raid 1 partitions.  You can have as many disks in the raid 1 partitions as you would like (even 0!) and you can put as many of these raid 1 partitions together as you want to make your virtual disk.